# Handling navigations in tabActivity

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, android-fragments

Im developing a application which uses the `tabs` with `fragments`. Google is providing `android support v4.jar`so that we can use the fragment for api 1.6 also.

I have gone through the sample provided by google in which there is no inner `fragment` for each tab
 ( i.e., Each tab is consisting of only one `fragment`) that can be easily handled.

**Now my problem is**, I need to achieve the navigation in the `tab activity` which consists of more than one fragment for a tab.

How can i achieve it?

Suggest some samples and some ways to achieve this.

Thanks a ton

Edit: Im using fragments because the `ActivityGroup` is deprecated.

Comment: What do you mean with 'achieve the navigation'? What does work and what does not work? Do you have one Activity per Tab?

Comment: U cant use the TabActivity for tabs. U can use only fragmentActivity for achieving tabs.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html.. Navigation in the sense handling the back with respective to tabs.

Comment: Well why can't you use the TabActivity for Tabs? It is meant for exactly that use case. What do you want to achieve exctly? Give an example please.

Comment: `TabActivity` is deprecated. For eg. i will have 3 tabs. Each `tab` may consists of 4 views. Now i have to handle the back, so that i can manage the tabs. (ie If im in `4th view` of `1st tab`, if i move to `other tab` and from there if i press `back`. It should come to `4th view` of the `1st tab`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FragmentManager (activity.getFragmentManager) in conjunction with FragmentTransaction to group changes like switching fragments. The FragmentManager supports a back-stack that allows you to rollback those transactions on back pressed which should be exactly what you need.

Comment: I have been trying this but cant able to conclude anything. The sample in api compatibility demo is not understandable. Can u provide me some samples

Comment: I got no example lying around and my Honycomb emulator does not work properly. What's wrong with the api demo?

Comment: Im using for android 2.0 onwards. Api demos came for the compatibility package doesnt run at all. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I never used that backport for fragments. Can you post a link to it? I'll set up a test-projekt and give you feedback.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html and the link for the tab activity using fragment activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html